# How can I reset the "password attempts" counter on the S6

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, pattern-lock

guys! I'll admit it, I was trying to unlock my mom's phone she let me borrow, and it closed for inactivity, and I didn't want to bother to go ask her, so I tried the password. Now I only have two more attempts until it resets itself, and I'm terrified of her finding out I tried the password. Is there a way for me to reset the counter so she doesn't see the message? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You already know the answer. Give the phone back to your mom!!! She knows the password and the problem will be solved immediately.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I know, but I don't want her to know!